# Javascript functions: var func = someFunction() and var func = someFunction?

Tags: javascript, function

```
 var funcHi = function() { 
    var a=6;
    var b=5;
    return a+b;
    };

var withBrace = funcHi();
var withoutBrace = funcHi;

console.log("With braces: "+withBrace)     //'Reference 1'
console.log("Without braces: "+withoutBrace)          //'Reference 2'
console.log("Without braces: "+withoutBrace())         //'Reference 3'
```

The code is pretty simple and clear. For 'reference 1' and 'reference 3', the console would show 11 but I'm not clear with where do we use 'Reference 2'. For 'refernce 2', the console would simply show the complete function instead of showing 11. Many times, we use 'reference 2' thing (e.g. window.onload = initAll) but how is it useful.

```
window.onload = initAll;  //What does it actually do? Why not 'window.onload = initAll()'
```

I am not clear about the concept behind it.
If possible, could someone give me a link to some good lesson on this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the first case**: `withBrace` contains the result of calling `funcHi`, therefore it's `11`

**In the second case**: `withoutBrace` references the function `funcHi`. Therefore `withoutBrace === funcHi`, you can say that `withoutBrace` is a function, the same function as `funcHi`. You can call the function `funcHi` via `withoutBrace` by doing `withoutBrace()` and get `11` - **which is the third case**.

```
var funcHi = function() { 
  var a=6;
  var b=5;
  return a+b;
};

//assigning the result of calling funcHi to withBrace
var withBrace = funcHi(); 

typeof funcHi;    //function
typeof withBrace; //number
withBrace === 11  //true, withBrace is 11, a result of calling funcHi

//assigning funcHi to withoutBrace
var withoutBrace = funcHi; 

typeof funcHi;           //function
typeof withoutBrace;     //function
withoutBrace === funcHi; //true, they are the same function

funcHi();       //11
withoutBrace(); //11, they return the same thing since withoutBrace points to funcHi
```

Comment: Ok, I got this thing. Now what does  it mean when we do like 'window.onload = funcHi' and not 'window.onload = funcHi()'. Even while setting out intervals or timeouts , we ue the same. Why?

Comment: @NavneetSaini `window.onload` should be a function, which is fired on window load. Therefore it should *point* to a function. Using `()` calls the function, and optionally returns a result. You *assign* the function, not the result of the function. So the proper way to do it is `window.onload = functionNameHere`.

Answer (score 1):

### CASE 1

```
var withBrace = funcHi();
```

In this case, `withBrace` will be the result of `funcHi`. It means that:

```
console.log(withBrace);
// 11
```

---

### CASE 2

```
var withoutBrace = funcHi;
```

In this case, `withoutBrace` is a reference to function `funcHi`. It means that:

```
console.log(withoutBrace);
// function () { var a=6; var b=5; return a+b; }
```

So, you can invoke it:

```
console.log(withoutBrace());
// 11
```

---

### window.onload = f;

When you write something like `window.onload = f;`, it is an event, and the function `f` will be execute
whenever the `onload` event of `window` has been fired. So the function `f` will fire **automatically**
without your order, It will fire whenever the browser decide (when it loads completely in this case).

It means that you must write a function for `onload`:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // do something
};
```

But you never execute this function by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`funcHi` is a reference *to the function itself*.

If you want to pass a function around (eg, to add it as a handler to an event), you do it like that.

You only add parentheses if you want to *call* the function and get its result.